# G Suite Marketplace SDK Test Installation Flow gone

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

The Test Installation Flow button has disappeared from our unpublished G Suite Marketplace apps in the Configuration page for G Suite Marketplace SDK settings in the Cloud Platform Dashboard. We use unpublished apps for QA purposes. Our published project, we see that Configuration page now shows 'Integrate with Google' button. This disappearance happened within the last few weeks. Is there some way to get the Test Installation Flow button back?

Regards,
LT

Comment: Do you have any update on this? We face the same problem and emailing Google didn't help...

Comment: We couldn't figure out the cause so we wound up creating a new unpublished app and on that one the button to install which is now called "Integrate with Google" shows up.

Comment: Thanks, we had the same problem, once we submit it for approval, whether rejected or under review, they are gone. Btw, where is that button? I have an unpublished app but the button is not in Configure page anyway.

Comment: It is at the top of the Configuration page where "Test Installation Flow" button normally was but is now called "Integrate with Google".

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Once we submit it the button is gone. That's stupid...

Comment: Hi, I have created a brand new project and configured the GSuite, still no button for "Integrate with Google". Where exactly is that page, can you please give me the screenshot?

Comment: Same here, I suddenly realised the "Test Installation Flow" was gone. Is that possible anymore? Would be really needed for QA testing.

Comment: The page is in 'Configuration' when you are managing the G Suite Marketplace SDK for your app in google developer console. With your application selected, go to API and Services, select Enable APIs and Services, then select G Suite Marketplace SDK, then select Manage, then on the left you should see 'Configuration' option. If you select that, the "Integrate with Google" is on the top. One thing is though that you may have to repeat the steps more than once for the 'Configuration' option to show up in the left menu.